# Why is my function outputting 0 (zero)?

Tags: javascript, function

This code is supposed to calculate two user inputs by multiplying them. However, the output is consistently 0 instead of would normally be expected ie 5*5=0. I am not sure why this is happening. Am I not passing the variables into the function correctly? I feel like I might not be properly understanding value vs. reference (I am currently learning javascript)

```
var x = document.getElementById("a").value;
var y = document.getElementById("b").value;
var button = document.getElementById("button");

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    calculator(x,y);
}, false);

function calculator(a,b) {
    var output = a * b;
    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = output;
    console.log(output);
}
```

Comment: You get the value of your fields only once, when your script is executed, probably when your page is loaded; the fields are then empty, hence the value of 0. Put the corresponding code (`var x = …;`) in your callback function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Omit the value capture, just grab the elements:

```
var x = document.getElementById("a");
var y = document.getElementById("b");
```

Then use the values as the function parameters.

```
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  calculator(x.value, y.value);
}, false);
```

You were grabbing the values when they were empty and passing those to the function.

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/rnuwsvne/4/)

Comment: Thank you! That was it! I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the script is treating the values as strings, try using parseInt(a) * parseInt(b)